# Solr multiselect field to return document with all match

Tags: solr

Need to know if querying below scenario is possible on a multiselect field

Doc1 - type_mv: 1,5,8,6

Doc2 - type_mv : 1,5, 8

When searched for type with 1 AND 5 AND 8 return only doc2. doc1 to be excluded as its non matching(has extra 6).

But solr is returning both docs with query

Comment: Having a second field with just the value sorted in increasing order and with a separator is probably the easiest way, i.e. `type_mv_match:"1-5-8"` you can then query directly against this value.